# Controllers sharing parts: How to include a controller's output from within another controller's view in Prestashop >= 1.5?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

In the shop's customer section I would like to render the user account menu  (which we can see by default when reaching `/my-account` URL) as a side column on some others controllers like the ones associated to **"/my-adresses"**, **"/identity"** pages ..

I thought I would have to create another controller which purpose would be to gather menu infos and only render the menu `<ul>` list. Then I could override Controllers such as *MyAccountController*, *IdentityController* to include this former Ctrl and then render its content as part of the views of those two other controllers views.

So how one can load a specific controller from another in order to render shared views between pages ? Which is the right/clean way to do that ?

I heard about `$this->getController()` but I did not find any snippet or implementation of what I'd like to achieve. I new to Prestashop but even if the code seems clear, I don't get the point here.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

After getting a bit deeper into sources, I ended up moving the menu *(initially part of the `MyAccountControllerCore` alias `my-account` template)* into a brand new Controller "MyAccountMenuController", in `/override/controllers/front/`.

```php
<?php
// In /override/controllers/front/MyAccountMenuController.php
// The "exposer" controller
public function display()
{
    // Do what ever you want to pass specific variables

    if (! $this->template) {
        throw new Exception(get_class($this) . '::display() : missing template.');
    }
    $this->context->smarty->display($this->template);
    return true;
}
```

I am now able to import this menu by adding the following snippet inside the `initContent()` method of each controller that are part of the customer account section (this means that each of them must be overridden, for more info about overriding controllers, see [documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Diving+into+PrestaShop+Core+development#DivingintoPrestaShopCoredevelopment-Controllers)):

```php
<?php
// In /override/controllers/front/MyAccountController.php
// The "consumer" controller
public function initContent() {
    // ...
    // Importing the customer area's menu
    $menuController = $this->getController('MyAccountMenuController');
    ob_start();
    $menuController->run();
    $this->context->smarty->assign('myAccountMenu', ob_get_clean());
}
```

I don't think the original purpose of `getController` method (located in ControllerCore class) was meant to include another controller output, at least in Prestashop 1.5. Still, to me this approach is far cleaner than duplicate views code.

If you have a better (cleaner) approach to implement such a mechanism, please let me know !

Any thoughts ?